# ISA 2006 - Can it route HTTP traffic to both standard and non-standard ports on the same physical server?

Tags: isa-server

I am working with an administrator at my company.  We recently added MS ISA 2006.  I do not have access to the server, so my question is more theory based.

Is it possible to setup ISA to route HTTP traffic to the same physical server using both standard port 80 and nonstandard port, say 8989?

For example,

internally, the address

http://myserver/

is pointed to by ISA externally as

http://myserver.external.com/

But, we have not been able to route traffic to

http://myserver:8989/

successfully with ISA.  Is this possible?  If yes, do you have any tips for doing so that I can relay to the administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have one Web Publishing rule already, for:

myserver.external.com /* -> myserver:80 /*

(myserver.exernal.com is the Public Name)
(The /* reflects a Paths entry of "everything")

You could easily change that to

myserver.external.com /* -> myserver:8989 /*

But now we're getting to what's probably the rub here - how are you disambiguating the exernal sites you want to publish?

You can only route one exernal namespace to one internal site at a time.

If, however, you wanted to do something like

myserver.exernal.com /app1/* -> myserver:8989 /* (or /app1/*)
myserver.exernal.com /* -> myserver:80 /*

You can (IIRC from years ago) - you just need to ensure your most specific rule is ordered first.

This will bounce requests for /app1/* to a different port internally (don't forget Link Translation in case of problems with internally-built URLs here), and allow all other requests to hit the other website.